# Why did my computer start speaking?

Tags: sound, alsa, soundcard

I restarted my computer because my audio crashed, and it scared the hell out of me when it just started speaking. It is going on right now. It says everything I write and it reads out the window and tab names. What could cause this, and how can I disable it?

Comment: please read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly and take out the caps - it's regarded as shouting and therefore rude. While you are at it, we need to know what os you are using.

Comment: A logical explanation would be that you have somehow enabled a disability aid that reads out aloud. I don't know how to enable or disable this, but I think someone here does. In the meantime, relax.. Cheers! 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check these settings in the Accessibility section...

[image]